# Non-scaling thumb skin Flash UIScrollBar AS3 alternatives

Tags: actionscript-3, scroll, scrollbar, flash-cs6, flash-component

There's probably a million posts about scrolling in AS3, but the problem I'm having is quite different. I have no problem making scrollbars *work* (have done loads of times), but I'm having a problem with custom skins. I'm basically trying to make the bar in this concept:

[concept http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/5081/screenshot20130507at140.png](http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/5081/screenshot20130507at140.png)

The key part is the thumb. When customising the skins in Flash, it scales the thumb bar (which hasn't been a problem in my [previous projects](http://www.sulsc.org), but in this one I want to have a non-scaled graphic like the [one in the concept.](http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/5081/screenshot20130507at140.png)

I've done a few searches and apparently this isn't easily achieved (something about extending the component class that I didn't really understand), but I find the UIScrollBar very easy to use. So my questions are:

1. Is there anyway to get UIScrollBar to do what I want?
2. Failing that, is there a third party equivlent of UIScrollBar that'll do what I want?
3. Failing those, what is the most pain-free way of making a custom scrollbar in AS3? (I realise there's a lot of tutorials for this out there, but there's *too many*, so if someone could point me towards a tutorial that doesn't require cause pain I'd appreciate it)

Thanks! (:

Comment: Did you try designing your thumb with 9 slice scaling on?

Comment: Yes, that's the default for component skins. The issue is that it's being scaled in the first place.